# GCC optimization effect on thread concurrency

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, optimization

I'm just fiddling around with threads and observing how race condition occurs while modifying an unprotected global variable. Simple program with 3 threads incrementing a global variable in a tight loop with 100000 iterations -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static int global;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

#define LOCK() pthread_mutex_lock(&lock)
#define UNLOCK() pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock)

void *func(void *arg)
{
    int i;

    //LOCK();
    for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        global++;
    }
    //UNLOCK();
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid[3];
    int i;

    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, func, NULL);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    printf("Global value: %d\n", global);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with -g flag and run the object 5 times, I get this output:

```
Global value: 300000
Global value: 201567
Global value: 179584
Global value: 105194
Global value: 205161
```

Which is expected. Classic synchronization issue here. Nothing to see.
But when I compile with optimization flag -O. I get this output:

```
Global value: 300000
Global value: 100000
Global value: 100000
Global value: 100000
Global value: 200000
```

This is part which doesn't makes sense to me. What did the GCC optimize so the threads got race conditioned for an entire 1/3 or 2/3 of total iterations?

Comment: do you see the same thing if you change the declaration to `volatile static int global;` ?

Comment: Add a `volatile` qualifier to the declaration of `global` and try again.  What does that tell you?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. You would need to look at the assembler code to try to see what it does, maybe the loops were optimized to `global += 100000;`. But don't expect it to make too much sense, you broke the contract of writing correct C++ code, the compiler therefore cannot produce correct assembler code.

Comment: Compile both with -S and see for yourself.

Comment: The optimizer does not bother generating code for that loop.  There is no point, it simply replaces it with global += 10000;  Have a look-see at the assembly listing, using -S.

Comment: volatile qualifier result with -O is almost the same with -g. Which meant the thread is picking up the latest copy of the global. And with non-volatile it was reading the global once and incrementing all at once. This clears my doubt.

Comment: The code you show only prints the global value once, right at the end of the main thread; it can't produce the output you claim with 5 values printed.  We can't debug the code you haven't shown.  Yes, optimization can alter the way things behave.  The optimizer might reduce your loop to `global += 100000;` for example.  Since you never use `i` and `global` isn't volatile, that's legitimate.

Comment: Since the behavior is *undefined*, the compiler is allowed to make the program print "elephant" instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely the loop got optimized to read the global variable once, do all the increments, then write it back. The difference in output depends on whether the loops overlap or don't overlap.